# Word embedding as features for classification

Tags: classification, natural-language, word-embeddings

W.r.t text classification, a common approach is to combine (often sum or average) word embeddings and use the result vector as features.

Are there any reference document(s) that establish the superiority of this approach for text classification over traditional feature engineering approaches?